# Projects in firebase console have disappeared but application works fine

Tags: android, firebase

I didn't do anything with database. Everything was fine. But one moment and in console I don't see ANY of my projects in firebase. But my applications still working which means database exists. How it is possible? What should I do?

P.S. People if you do -1 please let me know what is the problem with question?

Comment: Yes, I see that too. Write a message to the Firebase team too.

Comment: @AlexMamo it happens just recently or how long it takes in your case?

Comment: For me all https://firebase.clients6.google.com/v1beta1/projects/ requests are returning 500 internal server error. It's a waiting game until they fix it.

Comment: I see this question and check my firebase console. Yep, my project is gone too, it said `There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again`. Just give it some time

Comment: @BorisRuzanov It's the first time I'm seeing this. I don't know how long it will take.

Comment: @ZafkielDane yeah i see the same. I think google fixing it. i HOPE they are fixing it. but all development stopped...

Comment: I have the same scary error as well. All my projects disappeared. I tried to create a new project as a test, and I can't do that neither, I get the following error: 'quota exceeded for quota group writegroup and limit write requests per 100 seconds'. I submitted a support case as well

Comment: @nibbana did you check you quota on google cloud console?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I don't see any anomaly within the last 7 days in my quota. Even if I did, would that block the ability to create a new project?

Comment: @nibbana not suppose to. there are different types of quota but no quota on new projects

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I just created a new project. The problem was probably related to the current main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered in another same question, all `https://firebase.clients6.google.com` requests are getting 500 error

Services are OK, but you can not list, edit, add projects, and neither you can deploy to them

See this answer from a Firebaser here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61103273/2583487

> The Firebase console is indeed not listing projects at the moment.
>
> We are investigating the issue. We'll post updates to the status [dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/), and I'll update here too.

Answer (score 1):

It is working now, we can continue development

Comment: mine is not working.

Comment: Mine is working

Comment: Did u refresh the page

Comment: Yes i did. now its working. do you know what was the issue? did google make any post about that?

Comment: No they didn't post yet