# Is the Firebase Console is dead (not showing projects)?

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to open my Firebase projects, but unfortunately all projects are lost (not showing). My colleagues have the same problem.

Did anyone receive notification on Gmail about Firebase Console engineering works? When will it be available?

All services Storage, Auth, Firestore/Realtime, etc. are available, and data is not lost.

Comment: Same :( I hope they will fix it soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**The Firebase console was indeed not listing projects earlier this morning, nor were people able to access their existing projects in the console. The problem has now been fixed.**

For status updates, check the [status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/), specifically [this issue](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/20003).

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Frank!

Comment: IAM seems to be down in 'us-central1'. Is that the region that you're using. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103242/firebase-not-loading-projects)

Comment: Edit: I have removed my comment, Admin SDK as well as the Firebase started working right now. I guess the team has restored all the crucial services now.

Comment: Firebase storage does not show preload of image. If I clicked it before I could see what image is there. no I don't see anything

Comment: Hey Boris, I just checked a few of my projects and storage previews load without problems there. If it persists for you, can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, all `https://firebase.clients6.google.com` requests are getting 500 error

Don't worry, projects are still there and all services (databases, storage, hosting...) are working just well.

They should be fixing it. Wait & see

In the meantime, it is impossible to list, add, edit projects, as well as deploying to them.

Edit:
**It seems OK right now !**

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that the same is happening again? Since friday projects are disappearing, but they are still there in GCP.
But, no update in the [status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/)