# Firebase not loading projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Something weird happened today on the firebase page. I can't access any of my projects. When I load the firebase project's page it loads with an error of:

[image: g]

Does someone knows why this its happening?.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
The Firebase team acknowledge the problem and now its fixed!

Comment: What region are you in? IAM seems unavailable in 'us-central1'!

Comment: Yes us-central!. Where do you find that the IAM is unavailable?. On the GCP status page it all looks "good"

Comment: The logs all show problems accessing IAM. I can't upgrade support on my project as IAM isn't available :( :( :(

Answer (score 1):

As I answered in another same question, all `https://firebase.clients6.google.com` requests are getting 500 error

See this answer from a Firebaser here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61103273/2583487

> The Firebase console is indeed not listing projects at the moment.
>
> We are investigating the issue. We'll post updates to the status [dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/), and I'll update here too.

Edit:
**It is OK right now !**

Answer (score 0):

But #google and #firebase think it is ok, look the dash now: http://prntscr.com/rvhc67 and live: https://status.firebase.google.com/?authuser=0